# Can't open anaconda jupyter notebook: Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname)

Tags: python, windows, dns

On my Windows 7 64-bit, I installed Anaconda3 v4.4.0 in C:\Anaconda3. Now, after launching Anaconda Navigator, I can't launch jupyter notebook from there.

If I in command prompt run "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts>jupyter notebook", Chrome browser opened a new tab to "http://localhost:8888/tree?token=62d7eb16e2b7c5a9198ff6a84ec1056a00d60aeb99df55f0" but the content is

```
Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname) 
Your requested host "localhost" could not be resolved by DNS.
For assistance, contact your network support team.
```

The `hosts` file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\` has content as:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1 office.microsoft.com
```

what shall I do? seems it's a network or access rights issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually only need to check "Bypass proxy server for local addresses" in proxy settings.