# Does Microsoft Visual Studio Code has its own Python environment?

Tags: python, visual-studio

On my Windows 7 64-bit, I installed Anaconda3 v4.4.0 in C:\Anaconda3, however it could not launch Jupyter ([Can't open anaconda jupyter notebook: Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44754938/cant-open-anaconda-jupyter-notebook-network-error-dns-unresolved-hostname)), so I installed [Microsoft Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) then added [python support](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python), now i can run some simple python code such as

```
p = (4,5)
x,y=p
x
y
z=x+y
print(z)
```

Now my questions is, does Microsoft Visual Source Code has its own Python environment, or it's actually using Anaconda installed?

Comment: Did you get Python working with Visual Studio?  I recently went thru that routine and would be happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since VS 2017 it comes with an Python Environment itself. So I would say that VS Code uses that and not Anaconda.

Comment: Have you got any sources to back this up?

Comment: As you can see in the decumentation, you don't have to install a separate interpreter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/installation#visual-studio-2017

Comment: now you can select which Python environment to use.